# Reserve the same space a given picture would take

Tags: graphics

```
...
\usepackage{graphicx}
...
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=7cm]{demo.png}
\end{center}
...
```

And output...

[image]

But, that I want below the picture. Not `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}`, not shown image border. Like phantom. Save the sizes picture. That is, there is a image but whole white image. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not using `\phantom`, in a wrapper command named, say `\phantomgraphics`?

I've added a `\ifphantomgraphics` conditional to enable or disable the phantom feature. Just say `\phantomgraphicsfalse` to disable all up-coming phantoms and really use `\includegraphics`....

The `draft` key feature is really nice, but unfortunately it draws a frame and prints the file name -- which is not wanted here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifphantomgraphics
\phantomgraphicstrue
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\phantomgraphics}[2][]{%
  \ifphantomgraphics
  \leavevmode\phantom{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \else
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
  \fi
}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\blindtext
\phantomgraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}%
\hrule
\columnbreak

\blindtext
\phantomgraphicsfalse
\phantomgraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}%
\hrule
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Other possibility: Hook into `\includegraphics` and add a `phantom` key etc.

From a little conversation with `egreg` in chat (http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29085859#29085859)

The `adjustbox` package adds a `phantom` key to `\includegraphics`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
%\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\blindtext
\includegraphics[width=2cm,phantom]{ente}%
\hrule
\columnbreak

\blindtext
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{ente}%
\hrule
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect working... @Christian Hupfer

Comment: @Özgür: You're welcome as usual. Happy TeXing!