# Easiest way to quickly include or exclude all images from Latex file

Tags: graphics, pdftex, compiling

I have several images saved in pdf. However, due to the way they are generated, each are 800 Kb each. (The maximum size I worked with previously was 200Kb)

Each figure is included in the file in the standard way:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics{my pdf}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

This causes the pdftex to compile very slowly, and after compiling, the images will take a little longer to go from blurry to crystal clear. On average about 20 seconds but that is up from 8 seconds I am used to previously.

Is there a "switch" that allows me to turn on and off including images. Because when I work with the actual texts I do not need those images. This is when I wish to turn them off. After I have finished with the texts, and I want to add the images back in. This is when I should turn the switch on.

I have tried to put all images in a separate folder, and removing path to that folder, but of course that throughs a graphics not found error. Is there some better way to do this aside from commenting them all out?

Comment: `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}`, the image is not included then but a frame of the size of the graphics is drawn and the name of the file is printed.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Great! compiled in 5 seconds.

Comment: That's the cause of the `draft` option -- to concentrate on text content and to make compilation faster

Comment: This question (or one closely related) was asked yesterday:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318967/turning-off-and-on-images-in-figures-2  The answer specifically addresses the issue of slow compilation.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: This question is asked basically every day (at least very similarly) ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer In one form or another, you are right.